# Overlapping docks after installing dash-to-dock in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, gnome-shell-extension, dash-to-dock

I have recently upgraded Ubuntu from 19.10 to 20.04. Since updating dash to dock behaves abnormally. It works normal initially, later when i lock the screen then the problem starts.

[image: Look at the left]

When I logout and log in again it works fine until I lock the screen.

Comment: Does it get solved when restart gnome-shell ? ( press Alt+F2 and enter "r" , then press enter)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming that you've got the most current version of DtD, you'll need to do either of the following...

Disable `Ubuntu Dock` via the `Extensions Manager` or via https://extensions.gnome.org/local/

Or

```
sudo mv /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com ~/Desktop
```

Restart gnome-shell...

<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, in the box type <kbd>r</kbd>, then <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Comment: I tried the "purge" command, but apt-get was going to also remove "ubuntu-desktop" and "ubuntu-desktop-minimal". Is there an option to prevent it removing other packages?

Comment: @rjray Try `sudo mv /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com ~/Desktop`. Then restart gnome-shell, or log out and log in.